# "Cannot read property 'load' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm attempting to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) documentation to integrate with Google sign in, though I'm running into this error in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined`
        `at script.js:1`

`script.js`:

```
window.gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    console.log('Loaded!');
});
```

I get the error about half of the time, and inspecting the network panel in Chrome, it only happens when the following resource is **not** loaded:

`https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.d2dliHDvPwE.O/m=auth2/exm=signin2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNGAKhVlpzmTUpjFgzBXLpLM_oEFg/cb=gapi.loaded_1`

How can I eliminate this error?

If it's useful, here's my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Sign In Test</title>
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="*****.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding an onload event to the script tag. So change your script tag to

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=myFunc" async defer></script>
```

Then wrap your code in the callback function.

Answer (score 5):

Add `onload` param to the link, as in the docs: [google sign in docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#auth-setup)

If you do it in pure html/js, you can just add this excerpt into the `head` tag.

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=myFunc" async defer></script>
    <script>
    function init() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function() { // Ready. });
    }
    </script>
```

If you want to load gapi inside a react app (for instance create-react-app) try to add this to a component:

```
loadGapiAndAfterwardsInitAuth() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.onload=this.initAuth;
    const meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.name="google-signin-client_id";
    meta.content="%REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ID_OF_WEB_CLIENT%";
    document.head.appendChild(meta);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

 initAuth() {
    window.gapi.load('auth2', function () {
      window.gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: "%REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ID_OF_WEB_CLIENT%";
      }).then(googleAuth => {
        if (googleAuth) {
          if (googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
            const googleUser = googleAuth.currentUser.get();
            // do something with the googleUser
          }
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: How can i get %REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ID_OF_WEB_CLIENT%?
I am getting `googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()` as false. How can i get that as true?