# Blank page after running build on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, netlify

Trying to deploy create-react-app on netlify, however my build is blank page. I'm using .env file for loading firebase api key is that a problem for build?

Even when I tried to open it locally on my computer its blank page and it outputs an error in console: "Loading failed for the  with source “file:///event-app/static/js/main.108757a0.js”"

package.json: 
https://gist.github.com/Verthon/f82371ad2bb636b2e95c5b7697aa0bb5

```sh
➜  event-app git:(master) ✗ npm run build

> event-app@0.1.0 build /home/jurr/Projects/event-app
> node scripts/build.js

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/Router.js
  Line 12:  'withFirebase' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/Firebase.js
  Line 21:  'Firebase' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  282.86 KB  build/static/js/main.108757a0.js
  3.1 KB     build/static/css/main.8e671453.css
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting

```json
"homepage": "."
```

in `package.json` according to [this doc](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment)

Comment: I am getting a blank page even after adding "." as the homepage. Any clues on what else could be wrong

Comment: Yes, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63277866/2517147) below.

Comment: In my case the resolution was to add `onload` param to the loading google api scripts, as in the [google api client docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#auth-setup) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213061/cannot-read-property-load-of-undefined/53252605#53252605)

Comment: it resolved my issue but how can I host my application on github if i give my homepage a value like "."   ?

Comment: I faced the same issue even after adding "homepage": "." in my package.json. I changed my BrowersRouter to HashRouter now it works.

Answer (score 88):

If you're using `react-router` and trying to open `index.html` directly in the browser (or using electron, which essentially does that), in addition to setting `homepage` as others have suggested, replace your `BrowserRouter` with a `HashRouter`.

---

I was trying to build an electron app using create-react-app.  When running in development everything was fine, but when I built the CRA and then pointed the electron app to the `index.html` file, I got the blank page.

I found that that was exactly the same as opening the `index.html` file directly in the browser.  Everyone says "set `homepage` in `package.json`", but I already had that.  So what now!?

I eventually figured out that the problem was `react-router`.  I was using a `BrowserRouter`.  Switching to a `HashRouter` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Dude, saved my life also. do you have any idea as why HashRouter works?

Comment: `HashRouter` works because nothing after the "#" in the URL is sent to the "server".  That part of the URL is only interpreted by react-router.

Comment: thank's for you'r answer. this is work but after i tried click to another page cannot redirect.

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well, thank you very much! Do we know why though? Is this a known bug?

Comment: `HashRouter` worked perfectly, with `react-router-dom`.

Comment: THIS! Thanks for saving lives, man.
Do we have any Documentation where this is detailed?

Comment: This is proof that not all hero's wear capes. And if someone is interested in more details about HashRouter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976069/9231525

Comment: Using a HashRouter instead of the BrowserRouter fixed the issue for me while running the app on a prefix such as `www.site.com/appprefix/` and `PUBLIC_URL=/appprefix/` set during build. **However**, BrowserRouter also works fine if you explicitly set `basename=process.env.PUBLIC_URL`

Comment: Can we use this for our production environment like AWS ec2 and nginx?

Comment: this isnt working now, I am using react router v6. any help ?

Comment: For react-router v6, Switching to a HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter solved the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me when trying to serve the static content on AWS lightsail storage.

Answer (score 39):

Add

```json
"homepage": ".",
```

in your `package.json` then build again.

Answer (score 20):

Just as [@Verthon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9100781/verthon) said putting the `"homepage": ".",` in your package.json file, in the **top level** like this:

```
{
     "name": "myApp",
     "homepage": ".",
     // all other package.json stuff...
}
```

Comment: You saved me here thank you sir! Wonder why this isn't captured in documentation somewhere, unless I overlooked?

Answer (score 16):

Oooor as I just found out that I had done again and again: You published the *public* folder instead of the *build* folder.

[image]

Comment: I hate that this was my error. I wonder if there's a tutorial that says "for example: public" for build folder instructions that we both followed.

Comment: That could very well be.  But in my case it was just a momentary lapse of brain activity... :-)

Comment: D'oh! And how did I skip this suggestion two hours ago

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the root folder you can use `homepage`

```
  "homepage":"."
```

in package.json

if it's in any other folder like `https://example.com/admin` you can use

```
  "homepage":"https://example.com/admin"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a comment inside my `return` method and this caused the problem for me.

If the error message in the browser console is

> Minified React error #152;

Then removing any comment inside the `return` method might solve your problem as it did mine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the inline runtime script was not being run as I was getting the error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-5='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

This was fixed by adding the `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` variable to the build script.

```
"build": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false react-scripts build",
```

This is because of the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) of browsers: "A CSP compatible browser will then only execute scripts loaded in source files received from those allowlisted domains, ignoring all other script (including inline scripts and event-handling HTML attributes)."

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. But if you follow [React-Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/), correctly, you will realise that there is a  "homepage":"." // User "." if you are deploying on your local machine, but on a server hosted     somewhere you can use your domain or ip address the homepage field.

```js
{
  "homepage":"https://example.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and it was because i was importing useContext wrong

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It happened to me after deploying to GitHub page.

It is working to local but after deployment it is opening the blank page.

Problem is we changed the homepage path. So We need to update paths which are in our code.

If I give an example with my case, I added homepage into the "package.json" file something like:

```
"homepage": "https://[YourGitHubAccountName].github.io/[YourProjectName]"
```

So after adding this, app doesn't work because The paths which are inside of my code need to be change.

For example:

**'/'** paths should become **'/[YourProjectName]'** or

**'/test'** should become **'/[YourProjectName]/test'**

Answer (score 0):

I had a black screen when i was trying to map an undefined property

importing_file.js

```
<MediaImage  />
```

imported_file.js

```
export const MediaImage = props => {
    console.log("areas", props.areas)
    return (

        <div className={props.className} id={props.id}>

        <img src="../../favicon-flat.png" alt="Workplace" useMap={"#mapa"+props.id}/>

        <map name={'element'props.id}>
 {props.areas.map(m=>{} )}

        </map>

        </div>)

}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for `React` with `typescript` is to add `"homepage": "."` in `package.json`

```json
  {
  "name": "todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "scripts": {    
  },
  "eslintConfig": {    
  },
  "browserslist": {
  },
  "homepage": "."
}
```

now build the Application with `npm run build` and open the production `html` file.

Answer (score 0):

I installed react-outer-dom using

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

and deactivated my VPN.
It's now working.

Answer (score 0):

```
import '//css/Popup.css';
```

It gives no error unless you call a black screen of death an error.

Specify the path properly or better yet move it out of a component to be referenced in the index.js.

Answer (score -1):

simply change the private property value in your package.json to false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that didnt work for me and seems dangerous

Answer (score -2):

So the problem is with the caching of your app in the browser.

I have solved this problem with `serviceWorker()` in `create-react-app`.

Here is the solution: Just add this in you `index.js` file and remove service worker register

```js
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
unregister();
```

Answer (score -3):

I was trying to open the application after build with double-clicking the index.html and didn't work either, I got the blank page  but if the built files are run in a server environment works.  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Answer (score -7):

1. Run `npm run eject`
2. Edit file webpack.config in the config folder
3. Find path with "static/" or "static/js/" or "static/css/" in the file and delete such path
4. Build your project again

This work for me. hope this works for you, too.