# How do I host a React application to a regular domain? (e.g. http://somedomainnamehere.com/)

Tags: reactjs, npm, web-hosting, package.json

I have a static React application that I want to host. I have a domain available too, say `http://somedomainnamehere.com/`. I'm new to React and web hosting. I looked up some tutorials and tried adding `homepage` attribute to `package.json` but that doesn't work.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "http://somedomainnamehere.com/",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

After running the `npm run build` command, the message displayed is **The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.**

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what am I missing here? And if there's any other way to host my application?

Comment: you can use `AWS Amplify`

Comment: You could use heroku

Comment: @upog Hey, I looked up the steps https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-react-app-cicd-amplify/. This will host the application at ```https://<branchname>.<appid>.amplifyapp.com```. Can I override this to host it at ```http://something.com``` instead?

Comment: yes, `Route 53`. Careful with free tier usage when using aws service or you will get charged

Answer (score 0):

in your `package.json` file, change

```
"homepage": "http://somedomainnamehere.com/"
```

to

```
"homepage": "."
```

Then you can run `npm run build` once more.
Please refer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568697/blank-page-after-running-build-on-create-react-app)

After that, you can put content of `build` folder in virtually any host.

- If you have a shared hosting account, you can put it directly to
  `public_html` folder.
- If you have Heroku, you can follow
  tutorials to deploy static page like [this
  tutorial](https://medium.com/@agavitalis/how-to-deploy-a-simple-static-html-website-on-heroku-492697238e48).
- [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) is also nice and free place to host your new project.

Hope this helps.