# React build showing blank page

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build the react application for the production. Build is showing blank page but with our default background color.
Added homepage in package.json as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568697/blank-page-after-running-build-on-create-react-app) and rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face this problem when I'm using Cpanel if you're using Cpanel then using add a .htaccess file and paste this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ ./index.html
```