# I ma getting the white screen after deploying the react app in the azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, deployment, production

[`I am receiving the all files in console but showing in the frontend and automatically refresh showing the whitescreen`[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

[Package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpIyo.png)Q5XvT.png

Comment: could you share the errors from console?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. In order help us to get you the answer that you want, have a look at the [tour] and please take the time to read through [ask].

Answer (score 1):

To resolve white/blank screen deployment of react app in Azure, try either of the following ways:

1. In `package.json` add `"homepage": "."`
2. Make sure to publish from `build` folder instead of `public` folder
3. In your `index.html`, make sure to check to specify correct JavaScript bundle.

References: [How to fix the Blank screen After a Static Deployment with create-react-app](https://medium.com/@siddhantahire98/how-to-fix-the-blank-screen-after-a-static-deployment-with-create-react-app-2e76983a5d5d) and [I have deployed a azure-webapp and the page displays blank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/91848/i-have-deployed-a-azure-webapp-and-the-page-displa.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can see this other post: [Blank page after running build on create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568697/blank-page-after-running-build-on-create-react-app#answer-63277866)

If you're using react-router and trying to open index.html directly in the browser (or using electron, which essentially does that), in addition to setting homepage as others have suggested, replace your BrowserRouter with a HashRouter.

Comment: We talk about Azure deploy.