# Blank page after Create React App Build placed on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, react-router-dom

Previous note: No solution on the following post is working for me:
[Blank page after running build on create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568697/blank-page-after-running-build-on-create-react-app/63277866#63277866)

For my case, App.js main function:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path='/' element={<Login />} />
        <Route
          path='/home'
          element={<ProtectedRoute children={Home} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and index.js:

```
root.render(
  <div className="flex justify-center bg-black overscroll-contain">
    <div className="w-full max-w-[70rem]">
      <Auth0Provider
        domain={domain}
        clientId={clientId}
        authorizationParams={{
          redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
        }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Auth0Provider>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

The build is being placed in a subdirectory. I access it using a similar url to this one: https://test.myweb.com/MyApp.

I have tried both the suggested configuration on package.json: `"homepage": "."` and `"homepage": "https://test.myweb.com/MyApp"` and none works for me. At the same time, I have been trying to make a working .htaccess as follows, with no luck:

```
RewriteEngine on
    #for app in subdirectory
    RewriteBase /test/testingProjects/MyApp
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*/test/testingProjects/MyApp.* /test/testingProjects/MyApp/index.html [L]
    #for root app
    RewriteBase /
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    
    # DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|js)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

At this point I have different settings to check that I'm not sure how or what to set:

- `BrowserRouter` proper usage.
- Property `'homepage'` on package.json
- `.htaccess` file.

Worth mentioning that the login is built with Auth0 in case a special configuration is needed for this case.

The developer console show that the files are kind of reading, but it stops at root level not going further:

```
 <body>
   <noscript>This app requires Javascript to function.</noscript>
   <div id="root"></div>
 </body
```

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The build is being placed in a subdirectory. I access it using a
> similar url to this one: `"https://test.myweb.com/MyApp"`.

The React-Router-DOM router component assumes it is rendered at `"/"` and treats all routes and links as relative to *this* path. If you are hosting your app from a sub-directory then you'll need to tell the router this information via the [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) prop.

> ### `basename`
>
> Configure your application to run underneath a specific basename in
> the URL

If you are deploying/hosting your app from a `"/MyApp"` sub-directory on your server, then pass this as the router's `basename` prop.

```
root.render(
  <div className="flex justify-center bg-black overscroll-contain">
    <div className="w-full max-w-[70rem]">
      <Auth0Provider
        domain={domain}
        clientId={clientId}
        authorizationParams={{
          redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
        }}>
        <BrowserRouter basename="/MyApp">
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Auth0Provider>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path='/'    // <-- renders as "/MyApp/"
          element={<Login />}
        />
        <Route
         path='/home' // <-- renders at "/MyApp/home"
         element={<ProtectedRoute children={Home} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Following your answer, I added basename to BrowserRouter and I'm using 'homepage:".", but I still have the "blank" page (actually the web 'wants' to load, but it just reads up to  <div id="root"></div> (as before).

Comment: @Germán `"homepage": ".",` is likely correct. I don't know if a custom `.htaccess` file is necessary or if yours is correct. What type of server or hosting service are you deploying your app to? See CRA's [Serving Apps with Client-Side Routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) for a quick & dirty on using Apache HTTP Server, if that is what you have used.